Is the translation on torus $\mathbb{T}^2$ ergodic with the haar measure?
Let $f: \mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1$
$f(x,y)=(cx,y)$ such that $c$ is a complex number and $|c|=1$.
Consider the haar measure.
Is it an ergodic system? Why?
I would like to understand it.

Pick your favourite measurable set $B\subset \mathbb{S}^1$ such that $0<\mu_1(B)<1$ where $\mu_1$ is the Haar measure on $\mathbb{S}^1$. Denote by $\mu_2$ the Haar measure on $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1$. Note that $\mu_1 \otimes \mu_1$ is a $\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1$ probability measure (as $\mu_1$ is $\mathbb{S}^1$-invariant probability measure). Thus, by the uniqueness of the Haar measure on compact groups, we get $\mu_2=\mu_1 \otimes \mu_1$.
Now consider the set $M=\mathbb{S}^1\times B$. We have $f^{-1}(M)=M$, but as $\mu_1$ is a probability measure we get
$$ \mu_2(M)=(\mu_1 \otimes \mu_1)(\mathbb{S}^1 \times B)=\mu_1(\mathbb{S}^1) \mu_1 (B)= \mu_1(B). $$
Hence, $0<\mu_2(M)<1$ (as $0<\mu_1(B)<1$ by construction) and therefore $f$ is not ergodic.

Is f=T?  What definition ( haar measure ) did you use ?

@GabrielCorrêa Sorry, I meant $f$ (I am just used to call the map $T$). I am not sure I understand your second question. There exists only one Haar measure for every compact group. Note that the Haar measure of the product of two compact groups is equal to the product measure of the individual Haar measures (is this is the point of confusion?). I am happy to elaborate if you can specify which part troubles you.

This can't be ergodic system, because "it doesn't mix points enough".
Your transformation doesn't change second coordinate at all, so it only acts on fibres.
More formally, suppose that $f$ is ergodic. Then we should have for every $g \in L^1(T^2)$ and almost all $(x, y) \in T^2$ the ergodic theorem:
$$
\int_{T^2} g d \mu = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1 n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} g(f^k(x, y)).
$$
But for function like $g(x, e^{i\theta}) = \theta$ where $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ the equality would only hold for $(x, y)$ such that $y = e^{i\pi}$, which form a set of measure 0.
That's the first thing that came to my mind, but with such simple situation you should be able to prove directly from definition that there is no ergodicity.

Thanks ! Its an interesting approach.
